# INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR (nonce issue) when switching from sandbox to live

Tags: php, square-connect

I have been trying to get my web site set up integrating the ecommerce form into the site.  I managed to get it working using Sandbox credentials but as soon as I switched it to "live", replacing the location ID, application ID and access tokens for live data, and attempted to charge myself $1.00, I began to receive the following error:

```
Caught exception!
Response body:
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'category' => string 'INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR' (length=21)
          public 'code' => string 'NOT_FOUND' (length=9)
          public 'detail' => string 'Resource not found.' (length=19)
          public 'field' => string 'card_nonce' (length=10)

Response headers:
array (size=12)
  0 => string 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' (length=22)
  'Content-Type' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
  'Vary' => string 'Accept-Encoding' (length=15)
  'X-Content-Type-Options' => string 'nosniff' (length=7)
  'X-Download-Options' => string 'noopen' (length=6)
  'X-Frame-Options' => string 'SAMEORIGIN' (length=10)
  'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies' => string 'none' (length=4)
  'X-Xss-Protection' => string '1; mode=block' (length=13)
  'Date' => string 'Sun, 12 Jun 2016 22:20:11 GMT' (length=29)
  'Content-Length' => string '121' (length=3)
  'Keep-Alive' => string 'timeout=60' (length=10)
  'Strict-Transport-Security' => string 'max-age=631152000' (length=17)
```

However, I know the nonce was created since I received my nonce received alert in the previous page.

Here is the index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Payment Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

      // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
      // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
      // which is also available there.
      applicationId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //for public posting purposes
      inputClass: 'sq-input',
      cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
      },
      cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'CVV'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
      },
      postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: 'Postal Code'
      },
      inputStyles: [

        // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
        // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
        // input style below.
        {
          fontSize: '14px',
          padding: '3px'
        },

        // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
        // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
        // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
        {
          mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
          fontSize: '18px',
        }
      ],
      callbacks: {
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
          if (errors) {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
            errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
            errors.forEach(function(error) {
              var p = document.createElement('p');
              p.innerHTML = error.message;
              errorDiv.appendChild(p);
            });
          } else {
            // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
            alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));

            // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
            var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
            nonceField.value = nonce;

            // Submit the form
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
          }
        },
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
          // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
        }
      }
    });
    function submitButtonClick() {
      event.preventDefault();
      sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .sq-input {
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 1px;
    }
    .sq-input--focus {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #70ACE9;
      outline-offset: -1px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
    .sq-input--error {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #FF9393;
      outline-offset: 0px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>My Payment Form</h1>

  <form id="form" novalidate action="process-card.php" method="post">
    <label>Credit Card</label>
    <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
    <label>CVV</label>
    <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
    <label>Expiration Date</label>
    <div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
    <label>Postal Code</label>
    <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    <input type="submit" onClick="submitButtonClick()" id="card-nonce">
  </form>

  <div id="errors"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the process-card.php:

```
    <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/

# The ID of the business location to associate processed payments with.
# If you're testing things out, use a sandbox location ID.
#
# See [Retrieve your business's locations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/getting-started/#retrievemerchantprofile)
# for an easy way to get your business's location IDs.
$location_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';  //for public posting purposes

# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'; //for public posting purposes

# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}

# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}

$transaction_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionApi();

$request_body = array (

  "card_nonce" => $nonce,

  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "CAD"
  ),

  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);

# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transaction_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you registered more than one application with Square?

I believe this issue is occurring because the Square `application_id` you provide when initializing the `SqPaymentForm` in `index.html` does not correspond to the same application that issued the access token you provide in `process-card.php`.

The application that attempts to charge a card nonce must be the same application that generated the nonce in the first place.

Comment: Not entirely sure why it wasn't working, since the only place asking for the application ID is in index.html.  I had the token and location ID correct in process-card.php.  Taking your advice, though, I created a new application at the dashboard and started fresh with new credentials and got it to work!  A fresh $1.00 transaction recorded (less fees of course) on my dashboard.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that for me the problem was that my javascript file was stuck in a cache, with the sandbox key activated.  Once I cleared that cache it worked for me.